# Apache2 reading php files

Tags: php, apache2

I have a problem in Apache2. I changed my root directory to certain folder as in /var/www. I have php files under /html folder. Whenever I try to open any file under /html folder in web browser using link, it does not show anything.

This is how my "default" file looks like.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

DocumentRoot /var/www/

<Directory />
Options FollowSymLinks
AllowOverride None
</Directory>
<Directory /var/www/web/html>
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
AllowOverride None
Order allow,deny
allow from all
</Directory>
#
#<Directory /var/www/web/>
#<Directory /home/jenismodi/testFolder/>
# Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
#   AllowOverride None
# Order allow,deny
# allow from all
# </Directory>

#   <Directory /var/www/web/html/>
#<Directory /home/jenismodi/testFolder/>
# Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
# Order allow,deny
# allow from all
# </Directory>


ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
<Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
AllowOverride None
Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
</Directory>

ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

# Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
# alert, emerg.
LogLevel warn

CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

Alias /doc/ "/usr/share/doc/"
<Directory "/usr/share/doc/">
Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
AllowOverride None
Order deny,allow
Deny from all
Allow from 127.0.0.0/255.0.0.0 ::1/128
</Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

Can anyone tell me what am I doing wrong here ?

Thanks. 
JM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're forgetting to read your error log.